# How to show saved value in spinner from server?

Tags: android, soap, spinner

Below is my server response

> [{"METER_SERIAL_NO":5,"ACCOUNT_NO":58889,"KNO_NUMBER":57970099775448,"CONSUMER_NAME":"Nirmal chauhan","ADDRESS1":"Udaipur Rajasthan ","TELEPHONE_NO":9983835101,"MOBILE_NO":9983835101,"SANC_LOAD":8877,"TEST_TYPE":"0","COMPLAINT_NO":17448,"CIRCLE":1,"DIVISION":3,"SUBDIVISION":9,"TEST_NO":1884,"ACCUCHECK_NO":588,"FATHER_NAME":"Arjun lal","EXCEPTION_REMARK":"Fjdajjdcaacvb","METER_MAKE":null,"METER_CONSTANT":null,"CURRENT_READING":null,"PHASE_TYPE":null,"METER_TYPE":null,"METER_BOX_STATUS":null,"METER_TERMINAL_COVER":null,"METER_PUSH_FIT":null,"PUST_FIT":null,"METER_TERMINAL_BLOCK":null,"METER_DIGITAL_VISIBLE":null,"METER_FIGURES_UPSET":null,"METER_DIGITS_CHANGING":null,"SL_TYPE":null,"SL_ANYJOINT":null,"SL_COMMUNICATIONPORT":null,"SL_MTRLOCATION":null,"LI_EARTHLEAKAGEIND":null,"LI_REVERSELOADIND":null,"LI_BLINKINGOFLED":null,"SEAL_EXISTINGSTATUSMTRBOX":null,"SEAL_EXISTINGMTRBODY":null,"SEAL_EXISTINGTERMCOVER":null,"NEWSEALNO_MTRBOX":null,"NEWSEALNO_MTRBODY":null,"VERIFIED_BY":null,"POST":null,"CONSUMER_REMARK":null,"CERTIFICATION_NO":null,"DUE_CALIBRATIONDATE":null,"THREEPHASE_RPHASE":null,"MTR_DISPLAY":null,"MTR_DISPLAYLOAD":null}

I have below hard coded array list in my Spinner

```
String[] testTypeArray ={"None","Normal Testing","Emergency Testing"};
```

Below is my spinner Adapter

```
 public void SpinnerValues(){
        ArrayAdapter adapterrelation = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, testTypeArray);
        spnTestType.setAdapter(adapterrelation);
        spnTestType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                testType = spnTestType.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

        });

    }
```

Everything is fine.List showing perfect in my spinner. Now what i want that if "0" is coming from my server then its show "None" selected. If "1" then its show "Normal Testing" Selected. How can i achieve this ?

I am showing all other values in my EditText's. First all the data from server shows in all element then user review the data and update his data from the latest. and then press submit button then all data will also update on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use `spinner.setSelection(position)`

```
if(server_result.equals("0"))
{
   your_spinner.setSelection(0);
}
else if(server_result.equals("1"))
{
   your_spinner.setSelection(1);
}
else if(server_result.equals("2"))
{
   your_spinner.setSelection(2);
}
.
.
.
```

this should helps you.

Comment: Thanks Sathish. It Works perfect. Can u also give suggestion for radio group ?

Comment: kindly accept my answer. then only others can easily find the answer

Comment: what is question about radioGroup? post your question with new Thread

Comment: I already accept your answer but net speed slow so its updated late. same like spinner i have 4 radio button in radio group. so response coming from server and i want to show selected radio button what saved on server.

Comment: post this is in new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
spnTestType.setSelected(Integer.parseInt(serverResponse));
```